# Do not called UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded

Tags: iphone, uipangesturerecognizer

I use on the my UIImageVIew the

```
-(IBAction)handlePanFrom:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
```

and in the my code I try to use a two state:

```
if([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
{
      NSLog(@"Began");
}
if([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
      NSLog(@"End");
}
```

in the console I see a "Began" message every time when I start move the UIImageView, but no any "End" message...

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from apple doc:

```
UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
```

The gesture recognizer has received **touches recognized** as the end of a continuous gesture. It sends its action message (or messages) at the next cycle of the run loop and resets its state to UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible.

plz  try **UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled**

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I try this, but nothing happened, for both of state(UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded and UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled do not called). :(

Comment: @user1180261 what's the superview of your image view?

Comment: it is the base UIView of the .xib file.

Comment: @user1180261 and the user interaction of the image view set to YES?

Comment: Yes. Both of User Interaction Enabled and Multiple Touch option

Comment: @user1180261 try to NSLog the [recognizer state] at the beginning to check all the state of your recognizer.

Comment: @kroumvud, I wish you hadn't marked this answer as accepted, since it clearly did not work for you (and does not work for me either).