# Perform Long Press Gesture Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I am developing an sdk. I want to perform the long press gesture added to a view Programmatically. I have tried changing the state of the gesture recognizer and dispatching the message to the main loop but this does not perform the action

```
    for (UIGestureRecognizer *currentGesture in currentElement.gestureRecognizers){
        if ([currentGesture isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]]){
            UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture = (UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)currentGesture;
            longPressGesture.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan;
            [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.01]];
            longPressGesture.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged;
            [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.5]];
            longPressGesture.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded;
            [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1.0]];
            [longPressGesture reset];
            break;
        }
    }
```

This is what I have I tried. Can anyone help me resolve this?

This sdks are not meant for apps going to the appstore.

Comment: `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` is called or not

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik it is called

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740645/do-not-called-uigesturerecognizerstateended

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik... thanks for the help. Actually the code I have posted works. It was an issue at my end because it was picking an incorrect element. Cheers bro!

Comment: welcome bro....